# lxsession-default-apps fails to update

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, lxde, lxsession

Each time I run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, the program `lxsession-default-apps` is available for update but I always get an error that it can't update.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Fixed it by using `sudo dpkg --force-all -i [app name here]`